# How to apply a function to each group of IDs based on conditions with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I am trying to apply a custom function over a group of IDs only when some conditions are met for each column of that group (data should be only numeric and their sum non-zero). Here is the reproducible example:

```
dat <- as.Date("2021/08/04")
len <- 5
seq(dat, by = "day", length.out = len)

input <- data.frame(
  date = c(seq(dat, by = "day", length.out = len) , seq(dat, by = "day", length.out = len)),
  id = c("aa", "aa","aa","aa","aa","bb","bb","bb","bb","bb"),
  var1 = c(2,3,4,6,7,8,9,3,5,6),
  var2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3 ,4, 5),
  var3 = c("hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", 1, 2, 3 ,4, 5) 
)
```

Here is my custom Rescale function:

```
rescale = function(x,max_range=100){
  return(((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))*max_range)
}
```

And this is the desired output:

```
output <- data.frame(
  date = c(seq(dat, by = "day", length.out = len) , seq(dat, by = "day", length.out = len)),
  id = c("aa", "aa","aa","aa","aa","bb","bb","bb","bb","bb"),
  var1 = c(0, 20, 40, 80, 100, 83.3, 100, 0, 33.3, 50),
  var2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 50 ,75, 100),
  var3 = c("hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", 0, 25, 50 ,75, 100)
)
```

I am using the following lines to solve this, using dplyr:

```
out = input %>%
      dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
      dplyr::mutate_if(~is.numeric(.) && sum(.x) != 0 ,rescale) %>%
      dplyr::arrange(date, .by_group = TRUE)  %>%
      dplyr::ungroup()
```

The problem with these lines is that conditions do not refer to the columns of each group exclusively, but to the whole column of the `input` table. Hence, the function is applied to the whole table-column although the conditions are met only for one ID. In this example function was applied for `aa~var2` (which is not desired) and wasn't applied for `bb~var3` (which is desired).

Could you please help me correct the code of `out` ? Thank you.

Comment: Note that a column cannot be both numeric and character. You'll have to make it numeric first, apply the function, and then convert to character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you the desired output, but it is much harder than it needs to be because you want to preserve the "hi" values. A numeric column cannot have text in it, so you have to convert to numeric, handle NA values, rescale the non-NA values, then convert to character and rewrite the "hi" values in place. Furthermore, you need to go back at the end and re-convert the columns without "hi" in them back to numeric. You could avoid all this by having NA values instead of "hi", but anyway, if you really *have* to preserve the "hi" values, you can do:

```r
library(dplyr)

input %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(across(contains("var"), function(x) {
    x_n <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))
    if(all(is.na(x_n))) return(x)
    if(all(x_n == 0)) return(as.character(x_n))
    x_n[!is.na(x_n)] <- rescale(x_n[!is.na(x_n)])
    if(any(is.na(x_n))) {
      x_n <- as.character(x_n)
      x_n[is.na(x_n)] <- x[is.na(x_n)]
    }
    as.character(x_n)
  })) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(across(contains("var"), function(x) {
    if(any(is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))))) x else as.numeric(x)
  }))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    date       id     var1  var2 var3 
#>    <date>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#>  1 2021-08-04 aa      0       0 hi   
#>  2 2021-08-05 aa     20       0 hi   
#>  3 2021-08-06 aa     40       0 hi   
#>  4 2021-08-07 aa     80       0 hi   
#>  5 2021-08-08 aa    100       0 hi   
#>  6 2021-08-04 bb     83.3     0 0    
#>  7 2021-08-05 bb    100      25 25   
#>  8 2021-08-06 bb      0      50 50   
#>  9 2021-08-07 bb     33.3    75 75   
#> 10 2021-08-08 bb     50     100 100
```

If you are prepared to have NA values instead of "hi" (and thereby have numeric columns that you can actually perform calculations on), you can simplify to

```r
input %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(across(contains("var"), function(x) {
    x_n <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))
    if(all(is.na(x_n))) return(NA)
    if(all(x_n == 0)) return(x_n)
    x_n[!is.na(x_n)] <- rescale(x_n[!is.na(x_n)])
    x_n
  })) 
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>    date       id     var1  var2  var3
#>    <date>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 2021-08-04 aa      0       0    NA
#>  2 2021-08-05 aa     20       0    NA
#>  3 2021-08-06 aa     40       0    NA
#>  4 2021-08-07 aa     80       0    NA
#>  5 2021-08-08 aa    100       0    NA
#>  6 2021-08-04 bb     83.3     0     0
#>  7 2021-08-05 bb    100      25    25
#>  8 2021-08-06 bb      0      50    50
#>  9 2021-08-07 bb     33.3    75    75
#> 10 2021-08-08 bb     50     100   100
```

---

**Edit**

Removing the complication of having a non-numeric column altogether by having `var3 = c(1, 2, 3 ,4, 5,1, 2, 3 ,4, 5)` as suggested in the comments by the OP makes this far easier:

```r
input %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(across(contains("var"), ~ if(all(.x == 0)) .x else rescale(.x)))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>    date       id     var1  var2  var3
#>    <date>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 2021-08-04 aa      0       0     0
#>  2 2021-08-05 aa     20       0    25
#>  3 2021-08-06 aa     40       0    50
#>  4 2021-08-07 aa     80       0    75
#>  5 2021-08-08 aa    100       0   100
#>  6 2021-08-04 bb     83.3     0     0
#>  7 2021-08-05 bb    100      25    25
#>  8 2021-08-06 bb      0      50    50
#>  9 2021-08-07 bb     33.3    75    75
#> 10 2021-08-08 bb     50     100   100
```

Comment: Thanks for that Allan. I see your logic. Please, let me simplify the problem a bit and make `var3 = c(1, 2, 3 ,4, 5,1, 2, 3 ,4, 5)` as pure numeric . How would that change your code? Thank you.

Comment: @Telis that's _much_ easier - see my update

Comment: That is great Allan. Please allow me one last question. In my real problem, the names of the `var` columns are more complicated without following any specific pattern, hence `contains()` wouldn't really work. If I collect the var colnames in a vector of strings, e.g. `varnames = c("opel","wv","audi",etc.)` , how would that fit in your last code? Many thanks.

Comment: I think `mutate(across(varnames, ~ if(all(.x == 0)) .x else rescale(.x)))` works well. Many thanks Allan.

Answer (score 0):

```
  rescale = function(x,max_range=100){
    if(min(x) == max(x)) return(x)
    return(((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))*max_range)
  }


input %>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), rescale))
# A tibble: 10 × 5
# Groups:   id [2]
   date       id     var1  var2 var3 
   <date>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1 2021-08-04 aa      0       0 hi   
 2 2021-08-05 aa     20       0 hi   
 3 2021-08-06 aa     40       0 hi   
 4 2021-08-07 aa     80       0 hi   
 5 2021-08-08 aa    100       0 hi   
 6 2021-08-04 bb     83.3     0 1    
 7 2021-08-05 bb    100      25 2    
 8 2021-08-06 bb      0      50 3    
 9 2021-08-07 bb     33.3    75 4    
10 2021-08-08 bb     50     100 5
```

Comment: What about the `sum(.x) != 0` condition?

Comment: What about `bb~var3` ? Function should be applied to this as well.

Comment: @Julien i changed  the rescale function